# Simulating a hybrid dynamical system

Tags: code-request, differential-equations

I am trying to simulate the following hybrid ode

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x}=-\left(x-a+u\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $u$ is given by

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
u(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if} & x-x_d>\delta\\
0 & \text{if} &x-x_d \leq -\delta\\
u(t-dt) & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $a=10$, $x_d=9.5$ and moreover $u(t-dt)$ represent the value of $u$ in the last time step. $a$ and $x_d$ are known constants. I didnt know how to impliment this in mathematica.

PS: I was able to solve this with $\delta=0$. The controller simply becomes

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
u(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & if & x-x_d>0\\
0 & if &x-x_d \leq 0\\
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

```
a = 10;
xd = a - 0.25
simtime = 5;
var = {x[t]} // Flatten;
varInit = var /. {t -> 0};
f = -(x[t] - a + 0.5 (1 + Sign[(x[t] - xd)]));
DAE = {Thread[D[var, t] == f], 
    Thread[varInit == Flatten[RandomReal[{1, 2}, {1, 1}]]]} // Flatten;
sol = NDSolve[DAE, var, {t, 0, simtime}, MaxSteps -> 10000000];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], If[x[t] > xd, 1, 0]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 
  simtime}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, simtime}, {0, 12}}, AxesLabel -> {t, \[Theta]}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[{\[Theta][t] u[t]}, Above]]
Evaluate[{x[t]} /. First[sol] /. t -> simtime]
```

But I would like to implement this with a non zero $\delta$. For instance one can use a delta of $\delta=0.25$.

Comment: I tried solving it but got a `NDSolve::underdet` message "*There are more dependent variables, {u[t],x[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined*"; in case my failed attempt was due to my erroneous equation setup, perhaps [WhenEvent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) might seem useful

Comment: For me, WhenEvent was giving such error. So, I started using If function. BTW, how did u approach it? How did u make the solver access its previous values?

Comment: using [`WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html); If you're certain your system is correctly specified then I suggest you play around with `WhenEvent` until you discover a working specification. I could be wrong, but I don't think `If` can be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "last time step", since `NDSolve` uses an adaptive step size algorithm by default, and anyhow, the details of the numerical method shouldn't get into the mathematical model.

Here's an approach using `WhenEvent` that might be what you're looking for:

```
a = 10; xd = 9.5; δ = 0.25;
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == -(x[t] - a + u[t]),
  WhenEvent[x[t] < xd - δ, u[t] -> 0],
  WhenEvent[x[t] > xd + δ, u[t] -> 1],
  x[0] == 1, u[0] == 0}, {x, u}, {t, 0, tmax}, DiscreteVariables -> {u}][[1]];

Plot[{xd - δ, xd + δ, x[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
Plot[u[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first `WhenEvent` is triggered when `x[t]` crosses `xd - δ` from above and the second when `x[t]` crosses `xd + δ` from below.

Comment: By last time-step, I meant $u(t)=u(t^-)$. I will make this change. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not need greater accuracy, then you can use an explicit Euler

```
u[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, x[t] - xd > d}, {0, 
    x[t] - xd <= -d}, {u[t - 1], True}}]
xd = 9.5; d = .25; a = 10; h = 10^-2; T[0] = 0; x[0] = 1.5;

lst = Table[{T[i] = T[i - 1] + h, 
    x[i] = x[i - 1] - (x[i - 1] - a + u[i - 1])*h}, {i, 1, 1000}];
ListLinePlot[lst]
```

[image: fig1]